# Is there a chance that caffeine cache in springboot cause a 500 or timeout error due to too much data being cached?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caffeine-cache

Hi I am a newbie to springboot. I am using caffeine cache. Recently, I am getting a lot of 500 errors when the system calls an endpoint. The errors are like below:

`2021-09-17 00:37:12.127  WARN 1 --- [      Thread-33] c.g.b.caffeine.cache.LocalAsyncCache     : Exception thrown during asynchronous load`
`java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException: request timed out`

Can this be due to failing to read the cache successfully due to the data has expired or due to the data being too big?

Comment: As often users forget to add an exception handler to futures, Caffeine logs if an error occurs when computing the cached value. You can disable that in your logging library. This indicates that the http client had a timeout when fetching the remote resource in your cache loader.

Comment: Thanks @BenManes, I assume what you are saying is that the problem could be due to the remote resource not sending a response when the cache loader fetches from the resource?

Comment: Yes, the error type `HttpTimeoutException ` and message `request timed out` indicates that the http client failed to receive a response, canceled, and threw the exception to notify you that something seemed to be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the concise clarifications. Appreciate you help!